# Open Gnome terminal tab, run a command using C++ on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

There have been similar posts to this, but some things have deprecated (-x, -c) and there are enough solutions that I have to piece together that I think this warrants its own post.

I am running a C++ program from terminal (rosrun), and I want it to open a new terminal in the same directory, run a driver (executable file), and optionally switch the focus of the terminal to that new tab.

My current iteration is

```
system("gnome-terminal --tab -- 'bash -c 'ls; read'' ");
```

I've also tried

```
system("gnome-terminal --tab -- \"bash -c 'ls; read'\" ");
```

I'm using ls right now as a test command to tell me commands are working, the actual command would be

```
./path_to_driver/driver
```

This command successfully creates a new terminal, but I get the error "Failed to execute child process "bash -c ls" (No such file or directory)

Could anyone give me a hand with the syntax? Also, `system` is apparently bad so if there's an easy alternative that doesn't require >1 line and external packages that would be cool but `system` seems fine for my purposes.

Comment: Which are the similar posts that you referred to?

Comment: I'd guess you just don't need the quotes, e.g. `system("gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c 'ls; read'");`

Comment: That error message seems to indicate that there is no file or directory named `bash -c ls` (including the spaces in the file name), which is probably accurate.

Comment: Rather than guessing from within your program, I would guess from the terminal. That is, from the terminal's command line type in `gnome-terminal --tab -- 'bash -c 'ls; read'' ` and see what happens. (Presto! There is no longer any C++ relevant to your question -- a major simplification.)

Comment: https://imgur.com/UswHslO for other posts I've tried. All of your suggestions were good, thank you. Removing quotes seems to do it, and testing in terminal first was also a good idea.